# Using Excel To Find Best Results For Runners In A Race Series

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2013

Let’s say I have the following list of results from two races:

```
Name    AG  League  Pos_In_League   Race
Gareth Gareth   V40 MALE V40-49 LEAGUE  1   Race 1
David David SEN MALE SENIOR LEAGUE  1   Race 1
Chris Chris V40 MALE V40-49 LEAGUE  2   Race 1
James James SEN MALE SENIOR LEAGUE  2   Race 1
Paul Paul   SEN MALE SENIOR LEAGUE  3   Race 1
Gareth Gareth   V40 MALE V40-49 LEAGUE  1   Race 2
James James SEN MALE SENIOR LEAGUE  1   Race 2
John John   V40 MALE V40-49 LEAGUE  2   Race 2
Chris Chris V40 MALE V40-49 LEAGUE  3   Race 2
David David SEN MALE SENIOR LEAGUE  2   Race 2
Peter Peter SEN MALE SENIOR LEAGUE  3   Race 2
```

From this list, I want to show the best result each person got.  Some people may only do one race, while some will do both.  The results in this case would look like this:

```
Gareth Gareth   V40 MALE V40-49 LEAGUE  1   Race 1
David David SEN MALE SENIOR LEAGUE  1   Race 1
James James SEN MALE SENIOR LEAGUE  1   Race 2
Chris Chris V40 MALE V40-49 LEAGUE  2   Race 1
Paul Paul   SEN MALE SENIOR LEAGUE  3   Race 1
Peter Peter SEN MALE SENIOR LEAGUE  3   Race 2
```

Where

```
Gareth did two races and finished first both times – both results are the same
David did two races and finished 1st in race 1 and 2nd in race 2 – best was 1st @ Race 1
James did two races and finished 2nd in race 1 and 1st in race 2 – best was 1st at Race 2
Chris did two races and finished 2nd in race 1 and 3rd in race 2 – best was 2nd at Race 1
Paul only did race 1 and came third so his best was 3rd at Race 1 
Peter only did race 2 and came third so his best was 3rd at Race 2
```

Can I use Excel to make this determination, showing the full line of data in each case?

If this is possible, then a second question presents itself.  If a third race was introduced, could Excel tell me the best two races from three for each person?  E.g. in the example above, if Chris did a third race and finished first, his result would be

```
Chris Chris V40 MALE V40-49 LEAGUE  2   Race 1
Chris Chris V40 MALE V40-49 LEAGUE  1   Race 3
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort the table by name (primary) and result (secondary, best to worst).
Add a column on the right with a boolean, which will be true if and only if the name is *different* from the row above. Then filter on the True results in that column. For the second question, you can allow the name to be different from the one two rows above. You will need some edge conditions for the very top of the table.